# Aumento de consumo e Travamento de Aba, com o Script que sorteia números

Tags: javascript

Estava tentando realizar um script que sorteia 6 números de 1 - 60, sem repetição. O Script está funcionando, mas reparei que conforme eu vou testando/atualizando a página, chega um momento que o navegador aumenta muito o consumo de memória e a aba para de responder. Imagino que seja um problema no código, poderiam me apontar o erro?

```
    <script>
        var numerosSorteados = function(){
            var num = []; 
            var numero;
            var chave = true;
            var i = 0;
            while( i < 6){
                numero = Math.round((Math.random() * 60) + 1);

                for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    if(numero == num[j]){
                        chave = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(chave){
                    num.push(numero);
                    i++;
                    }
                    document.write(numero+"</br>");
                    chave == true;
            }
            return num;
        }
        document.write(numerosSorteados());
    </script>
```

Comment: Você tem razão, este código mesmo que simples devora o processador e a memória, isso porque estou utilizando um I7 com 08 gigas de memória, caracaaaaaaassss...javaScript maldito esse kkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Faça desta forma que ficara mais rápido, pois ele não recria o `array`.

```
    var numerosSorteados = function(){
        var maximo = 60;
        var resultados = 6;

        var i, arr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }

        var p, n, tmp;
        for (p = arr.length; p;) {
            n = Math.random() * p-- | 0;
            tmp = arr[n];
            arr[n] = arr[p];
            arr[p] = tmp;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < resultados; i++) {
            document.getElementById('out').innerHTML +=  arr[i]+ ', ';
        }
};
```